# Ошибка ajax запрос с использованием jquery на django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Я делаю ajax запрос с использованием jquery на django но у меня выводиться вот такая ошибка

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/test 500 (Internal Server Error)

Из-за чего выводиться такая ошибка?

Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#load").bind("click",function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"test",
                type:"POST",
                data:({num:'asd'}),
                cache: false,
                dataType:"html",
                beforeSend:funcBefore,
                success:function(response){
                    alert('success');
                },
                error:function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
     );
```

Comment: 500 ошибка сервера, что происходит на сервере? Смотрите логи.

Comment: в консоли браузера пишет http://127.0.0.1:8000/test 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Я увидел, посмотрите логи `django`, поставьте `debug=True`, или сервер поломался, или Вы отправляете что-то не то